# Building Brackets Shell (After running the grunt build command)

Tags: adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

On windows after running the grunt build command for creating brackets shell it gives done without errors but i dont see any .exe file generated..

What might be the problem???

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Are you following the [full brackets-shell build instructions](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-brackets-shell), including all prerequisites?
2. Make sure Brackets isn't running at the same time. The build will fail silently if the .exe file is currently in use ([see bug](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/3674)).
3. Try with a fresh git clone of the repo. If your brackets-shell local copy has been around for a while, sometimes the build & deps folders can get in a bad state. (I'm assuming you haven't modified the source at all. If you have, try with an unmodified copy of the source first to make sure it builds correctly without any of your changes).
4. Check that `python --version` shows 2.7.x

Verbose build output would also be helpful in diagnosing issues like this, but unfortunately there's [not yet](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/5100) an easy way to get that...

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the instructions on bracket-shell's wiki page, the Windows executable should be created in the `Release` directory.